# Errant line break in the "Forrester Consulting TEI Study: Five ways Stack Overflow for Teams delivered 191% ROI" blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

[image: screenshot of the blog post with the error]

There's an errant linebreak in [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/09/13/forrester-consulting-tei-study-five-ways-stack-overflow-for-teams-delivered-191-roi/) listicle. Could it be fixed please?

Comment: *[listicle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/listicle#Noun)* - *"An article based around a list."*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum is this a confirmation the word is used correctly? ;)

Comment: Anyway, this looks like the result of using some automated tool that splits long text to paragraphs based on word/letter count. I'll have to look deeper though, and in other blog posts.

Comment: And if I may be a little blunt, a need, a need for... proofreading