# The title of the blog post "The many strengths of neurodivergence" has a junk object ￼

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, unicode

In the recent blog post [The many strengths of neurodivergence](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/04/the-many-strengths-of-neurodivergence%ef%bf%bc), the title has a junk object.

**Screenshot from blog post**:

[image: header of the blog post]

**Screenshot from Stack Overflow sidebar**

[image: title of blog post in site's sidebar]

Comment: The ￼ struck once again: [Five nines, four ￼, one bugged blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382250/five-nines-four-one-bugged-blog-post)

Comment: Yeah, same author. Looks like he copy and paste, and not checking up after submitting. One time is totally normal, people don't notice. But same thing exactly, shortly after? That's not normal and just very annoying.

Comment: To the author's defence, the character may be ***invisible*** in some views or web browsers on a particular operating system in  a particular configuration. For instance, on [this page](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65526) (same line as "OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER", second column). But not if copy-pasted into a text document from that web page (on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (yes, I know), Firefox 105.0 and [Geany](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/) "Bemos", respectively).

Comment: Can confirm that I don't see the "OBJ" box symbol on my system (Mac OS 12.4, Chrome version 105.0.5195.125), either in the current blog post title or in the link @This_is_NOT_a_forum posted.

Comment: @V2Blast I saw it in my mobile couple of hours ago... but now it's not there. Looks like it has been fixed.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not seeing the issue now in blog post and SO side bar. It has been fixed.

Comment: @Arulkumar: Cool, thanks. I'll tag this as [status-completed], then.

Comment: @V2Blast I appreciate the fact that you are adding the relevant tags but it would be great if you can ask the relevant staff member to explain why this issue happened more than once and what they are doing to fix this such that it doesn't happen once more :)

Comment: @RandomPerson: See Ryan Donovan's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a weird one that is only visible and fixable in certain views in our CMS. When the original author lays this out, the `obj` is not visible. I've caught these in the past, but there's a handful of us posting these, so they'll sometimes slip through.

As always, appreciate the heads up on any errors that make it through to you all.

Comment: Which CMS do you people use?

Comment: In most modern systems (I tested in [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)), the regular expression `\x{FFFC}` would positively identify [it](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65526) (even if it is invisible). Perhaps a small automation project for Popper? (A regular expression for identifying the more common troublesome ones (source code-oriented though—some are perfectly acceptable in normal text): `\x{00A0}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2212}|\x{00E4}|\x{FFFC}|\x{FFFD}|\x{2217}|\x{200C}|\x{202B}|\x{202A}`)

Comment: @RandomPerson I found the following in the blog's footer section: `© 2022 All Rights Reserved. Proudly powered by WordPress`. So, I hope they are using WordPress CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Worth adding there seems to be a typo in the blogpost that causes the paragraph to split:

> In today’s podcast, Matt and Ceora talks with Wesley Faulkner, senior community manager at AWS CIoud, and Mariann Lowery, Product / UX Research Lead here at Stack Overflow about
>
> their experience as neurodivergent individuals and how we can all do a better job supporting our teammates while taking steps to feel more empowered in our own differences, too.

Comment: [Errant line break in the "Forrester Consulting TEI Study: Five ways Stack Overflow for Teams delivered 191% ROI" blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382017/errant-line-break-in-the-forrester-consulting-tei-study-five-ways-stack-overfl) also happened and reported here. It's fixed at some point but I feel like a quick post publish skim-over would sort these sorts of issues before anyone notices.

Comment: I made a separate post for the reported issue already: [Line break and typo issues in the blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382534/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar I hadn't noticed, it's been said reports about the same item should be grouped in the same question... The question also didn't have a link to the other post.

Comment: Since there's a separate post for this issue, we'll follow up regarding this issue there.

Comment: This has been fixed now. [See my answer to Arulkumar's linked post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382570/335251)