# Line break and typo issues in the blog post "The many strengths of neurodivergence"

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, spelling, linebreak

In the recent blog post [The many strengths of neurodivergence](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/04/the-many-strengths-of-neurodivergence%ef%bf%bc), there are two issues there:

1. The content of "... Stack Overflow about their experience as ..." is split into two paragraphs, line break is missing here. It is supposed to be in one paragraph.

   > [image: paragraph into two]
2. Instead of the word "Cloud", it is displayed as "CIoud". The "l" is replaced with a capital i, "I"

   > [image: Cloud typo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these issues (plus another minor typo) have now been fixed. This paragraph now reads:

> In today’s podcast, Matt and Ceora talk with Wesley Faulkner, senior community manager at AWS Cloud, and Mariann Lowery, Product / UX Research Lead here at Stack Overflow about their experience as neurodivergent individuals and how we can all do a better job supporting our teammates while taking steps to feel more empowered in our own differences, too.

Comment: Will there be any proof reading of future blog posts like this? There have been a lot of these seemingly minor, but yet highly annoying issues lately, which could've easily been prevented.